# JavaFX TableCell has null item

Tags: java, javafx

I have a controller, configured in fxml, which has TableView defined. I'm calling getColumns() on TableView in initialize() method and get column defiened in fxml by id, then I call setCellFactory and init new TestCell class. In updateItem() method TableView property is null. Any advice?

```java
class SomeClass {
 @FXML
 private TableView<someClassWithTableElems>someTableView;

 @FXML
 public void initialize(){
  someTableView.getColumns().get(5).setCellFactory(col -> new TestCell());
 }

}


class TestCell<S> extends TableCell<S, someClassWithTableElems>{
 @override
 protected void updateItem(someClassWithTableElems col, boolean empty) { //col is null
}
```

Comment: Advice on what? How to handle the null? How to make it not be null? Please try to be more specific.

Comment: How to make it not null, i would like to use data in my custom TableCell, that contains in someClassWithTableElems

Comment: You need to tell the `TableColumn` how to retrieve the needed data, which is done by setting the [`cellValueFactory` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty).

Comment: Yep, thx, that was it!